# Many-to-many relationship with duplicates

Tags: database

I am wondering which is better in the following case I have table `PRODUCTS` and I have table `ORDERS`, there is a many-to-many relationship between these tables and it is true that one product can appear many times in the same order. So the table connecting them could look like this:

`PRODUCTS_IN_ORDERS(ID, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID)` and then I will have data in the table like this
 `(1, 2, 3) (2, 2, 3)` to represent that product with `ID=2` appears twice in order with `ID=3`.

Or like this `PRODUCTS_IN_ORDERS(PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID, AMOUNT)` and then I will just have this record `(2, 3, 2)`.

My question is which of thoose two aproaches is better and why?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend with your use case, the first one `PRODUCTS_IN_ORDERS(ID, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID)` would be useful in a scenario where attributes in the related tables don't change for any association. That way the `AMOUNT`(assuming it's a field in `PRODUCT`) of the `PRODUCT` remains the same in an `ORDER` no matter how many they are.

The other one, would be useful for the opposite, where you want unique `AMOUNT`s for same `PRODUCT`s, so the `AMOUNT` is stored in the relation table, unique only to that `product` and `order` that are associated. this would result in multiple `product`s with different `amount` on the same `order`.

Comment: I am not sure you got the question correctly. My idea is that you can have one product many times in the same order. For example, you can order Cola twice in one order.  And in the same time you can have Cola in other orders and the same order can have other products also.

Comment: Oh, so the `AMOUNT` is the number of times the product appears in an oder, and the one with the `ID` has multiple entries for each product in an order?

Comment: Yes, exactly! `AMOUNT` is the number of times the product appears in an order and the one with the `ID` has multiple entries for each product in order

Comment: The one for `ID`s would mean a new insert to relation table each time a product in that order, meaning fetching this data and aggregating it might be expensive compared to fetching just a single record as with the `AMOUNTS` option, but it would allow for extra unique information that can be stored in the join table as i earlier thought, like a unique price for each time a product is there, or something like that, unlike in the `AMOUNTS` option.